# Remove and count duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

How to remove duplicate entries and how to count the number of duplicate entries in Microsoft Excel?

- For example, I have 100 values in a column, in which 5 are unique values.
- I want to find out the 5 Unique Values and the count of unique value, such as first value 21 times 2nd value 19 times and so on.

Comment: Hi a VBA solution is :add them into a dictionary and retrieve items from the dictionary

Answer (score 2):

My [Duplicate Master](http://www.experts-exchange.com/A_2123.html) addin will do all this and more

It includes options to handle strings for either *duplicate* or *unique* summaries for

- Case Insensitive matching
- `CLEAN` and or `TRIM` the data
- ignore all whitespace
- even using regular expressions

[image]

Comment: **Moderator Note** - I've reviewed this post and the link, there are no paywalls / etc to consider. Additionally, full disclosure is made, and it answers the question well.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for your note. I'm a little surprised this was flagged, all articles at that site outside the paywall and are freely available. Else I wouldn't have posted it originally.

Comment: I think there's some .. trepidation in general .. where that domain is concerned. Don't worry about it, it's a perfectly good and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have your list such that every ROW is a record (opposed to every
   COLUMN a record)
2. Make sure your list has a header row with a unique name for each
   column.
3. Select your list
4. Create a pivot table
5. Drag your entry column to Row Label
6. Drag the column to Values as well
7. For this column make sure it reads Count of , if this is not the case then change this by leftclicking it and selecting Value Field Settings, there you can select Count for the **Summarize value field by**.

Done

Comment: no need for two columns, just need to drag the column to Row Label and drag the same column to Values and show a count

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your existing list to its right, put names at top of the two lists, then create pivot table with first list as row labels. Make the second list as value to report on, and set its field setting to 'count'. Alternatively, you could put all 1's in the second list and set its field setting to 'sum'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy the column, then highlight that and choose Data -> Remove Duplicates in the Ribbon to make a unique list. Then to the right of the unique list, just use =CountIf() to find out how many there are.

For example, if your unique list is in B and the full list in A, just write:

```
=Countif(A:A,B1)
```

I agree pivots are great but if you don't like them (like me, for some reason) then formulas may be a good route.